# Extracting percentage of total year and categorise wise in r

Tags: r

The sample data is as follows :

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
Year <- c(rep(2014,36),rep(2015,36),rep(2016,36))
Month <- c(seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12),seq(1:12))
Category <- c(rep(c("A","B","C"),12),rep(c("A","B","C"),12),rep(c("A","B","C"),12))
Value1 <- c(sample(1:1000,108))
Value2 <- c(sample(1:10000,108))
df <- data.frame(Year,Month)
df <- df %>%
      arrange(Year,Month)
df$Category <- Category
df$Value1 <- Value1
df$Value2 <- Value2
```

I want to get the percentage share of both 'Value1' and 'Value2'  of each cateogory monthwise for each year. There are around 1000+ categories and 7years of data. The sample output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate percentage for each `Category` and `Year` and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Category, Year) %>%
  mutate(across(Value1:Value2, ~prop.table(.) * 100 , .names = '{col}_perc')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Value1:Value2_perc)
```